# Convert time object

Tags: javascript, object, time, timestamp

I'm trying to convert a time object, which is gathered from a xml file - 
this is the format: 2016-07-27T15:01:02Z

```
var times = [];
var time = $(this).find("time");
times.push(time);
```

this is the part of the code, where it's read and stored.

```
alert(times[1]); // Returns [object, Object]
alert(times.pop(1)); //Returns [object, Object]
```

I tried toLocalTime and so on, but I'm not able to get the time.
It only returns undefind.
How can I transform this Object to an time string or anything i can work with? or at least get the time out of the object?

thank you!

edit:

```
 var map;
    var heatmap;


    //Get Div && Set Settings for Map
    function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 30,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }); 

    //LOAD DATA

 $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "path to file",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {
var points = [];
var times = [];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
$(xml).find("trkpt").each(function() {
  var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
  var lon = $(this).attr("lon");
  var time = $(this).find("time");
  var p = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
  points.push(p);
  bounds.extend(p);
  times.push(time);        
});
```

the html is a simple

```
 <div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to post you HTML for me to know what `$(this).find('time')` returns, but doing this you can see what the object looks like.

Have you tried:

```js
var times = [];
var time = {name: "This is the object that that $(this).find('time') returned"};
times.push(time);

// What you have
alert("What you have: " + times[0]);

// What might work for you
alert("What might work for you: " + JSON.stringify(times[0]));
```

On a side note: (You may know this already, but no one told me when I started and it changed my life when I found out) If you are using Chrome (or almost any other browser for that matter), you can hit F12 to get the dev tools. Then go to the "Console" tab and then you can use `console.log('message')` instead of `alert('message')`. Doing this you can log objects without `JSON.stringify(..)` and you also don't have to keep pressing "okay" on the popups to get the next one.

Comment: this returns the keys like:
{"0":{},"length":1,"prevObject":{"0":{},"context":{},"length":1},"context":{},"selector":"time"}
but im still to blind to see, how i can get the time value: like 15:01:02

Comment: So that is the DOM element from the HTML. I don't know what the google API returns, but you can try `$(this).find("time").val()` or `$(this).find("time").html()` or `$(this).find("time").text()` .. I would need to see the whole object that `$(this).find("time")` returns, but you can try those.

Comment: you did't it! .text() got what i wanted! thank you, sir!

Comment: No problem :) Only happy to help